# latin-1 to utf-8 database

Tags: mysql, database, encoding, utf-8, diacritics

I have a database that is uft8_general_ci, only problem is up until this point an application coded by a previous developer seems to have been working with the database in latin-1.

I have since changed how the app uses the database and can now store an umlaut as an umlaut instead of Ã¼.  The problem now is that the application reads the previously existing data from the database as (example) 'SÃ¼ddeutsche' instead of 'Süddeutsche'.

Is there anyway to convert the data inside the database from one format to the other?

Regards

Edit:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName MODIFY ColumnName ColumnType CHARACTER SET latin1;
ALTER TABLE TableName MODIFY ColumnName ColumnType CHARACTER SET binary;
ALTER TABLE TableName MODIFY ColumnName ColumnType CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

This worked for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to correct double-encoded UTF-8 strings sitting in MySQL utf8_general_ci fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951871/how-to-correct-double-encoded-utf-8-strings-sitting-in-mysql-utf8-general-ci-fie)

Comment: Thank you, not quite the same but the answer works!

Comment: After some testing if I run this 2x on some of my columns the data will break - all data after a particular character/point are lost. Is this simply because I ran the command 2x, or is there a change its breaking lots of my data all over the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://blog.hno3.org/2010/04/22/fixing-double-encoded-utf-8-data-in-mysql/

Using what is listed here has fixed all my problems. I used this with my live data and have had no issues!

Answer (score 2):

You could try `SET NAMES` to let the Database talk in `latin-1` with your application while storing in `utf-8` or you will need to convert all previous Datasets to `utf-8`-Strings

Answer (score 1):

try

```
ALTER DATABASE your_db DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci';
```

and

```
ALTER TABLE a CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci';

ALTER TABLE b CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci';
ALTER TABLE c CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci';
```

don't forget to replace the 'ß':

```
UPDATE a SET field_1 = REPLACE(field_1, 'ß', 'ss') WHERE label LIKE '%ß%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a SQL function that I used in my db to cast all data codification from latin1 to UTF8:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateColumnEncoding(IN db_name VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE tableName VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE columnName VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
        FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = db_name 
          AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'text', 'tinytext', 'mediumtext', 'longtext');
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    OPEN cur;

    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO tableName, columnName;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        SET @s = CONCAT('UPDATE `', tableName, '` SET `', columnName, '` = CONVERT(CAST(CONVERT(`', columnName, '` USING latin1) AS BINARY) USING UTF8)');
        PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cur;
END //

DELIMITER ;

CALL UpdateColumnEncoding('your_database_name');
```