# Which PHP function decodes German umlauts? (ä, ö, ë)

Tags: php, special-characters

As html_entity_decode() seems not be the right one - you know how to decode these entities?

```
&#246; --> ö 
&#228; --> ä
&#252; --> ü
```

This are only examples - I've no complete list, therefore a general function would be nice - not a char by char replacement.

html_entity_decode() results only in something like Ã¶ instead of ö.

Comment: What PHP version are you using? Everything < 5.4.0 will use ISO8859-1, everything >= 5.4.0 UTF-8 as the default encoding.

Comment: PHP: 5.4.7 - and the html screen is not the problem - I need it as an ö in the database!

Answer (score 1):

you must set your html header to UTF-8 encode!!!

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

see here to change your text encoding on MySQL database:
[latin-1 to utf-8 database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879564/latin-1-to-utf-8-database)

Comment: ...you actually did read the answer, did ya?

Comment: See above - the html screen is not the problem. I get the string from outside - and need to save it as an ö to the database.

Comment: @Petra `&#252;` should decode to "ü" encoded in UTF-8 just fine using `html_entity_decode`. It appears that you're not handling this UTF-8 encoded string correctly afterwards.

Comment: set your TEXT/VARCHAR/whatever fields to utf-8 instead of latin on MySQL db

Comment: @deceze When I save it directly to the DB, I've `&#252` in the DB. When I make a html_entity_decode() first and save it to the DB afterwards - the string is cut off before the first umlaut...

Comment: @G_G It is UTF-8 already. I'm blond but not a noob. ^^

Comment: @Petra Again: you are not handling UTF-8 correctly! See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through, [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/), [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).

Comment: so be more specific: where exactly do you get the string Ã¶ instead of ö?

Comment: Sorry... my fault.. on the server was only PHP 5.3.10 - thought it was higher. Therefore he couldn't handle it. As he decodes it as ISO...