# How to replace broken German Umlauts with MySQL REPLACE function?

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8, replace

*(I accidentially asked this question first on DBA but found out in the FAQ to ask SQL questions here on SO instead)*

I'm trying to "repair" a MySQL database (UTF-8 collation) that was imported from an encoding-broken SQL text file.

I.e. the [German umlauts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanic_umlaut) are broken inside the database. What should read e.g. "ü" is displayed as "Ã¼".

Since I'm aware of the [`REPLACE` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace), I first tried the obvious:

```
SELECT * FROM `mydb`.`mytable` WHERE `mycolumn` LIKE '%Ã¼%';
```

This gave me the expected results.

Next I tried to replace them:

```
UPDATE `mydb`.`mytable` SET `mycolumn` = REPLACE(`mycolumn`, 'Ã¼', 'ü');
```

To my surprise, this resulted in zero rows affected.

So even [knowing a lot about encoding](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html), I still cannot figure out how to solve this (or whether it is possible at all).

**My question:**

How to use the `REPLACE` function to replace broken German umlauts?

Comment: I assume you can't reimport with the proper encoding? What tool are you using to make the queries?

Comment: Can you re-insert the data with "SET NAMES utf8"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to correct double-encoded UTF-8 strings sitting in MySQL utf8\_general\_ci fields?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951871/how-to-correct-double-encoded-utf-8-strings-sitting-in-mysql-utf8-general-ci-fie)

Comment: @fab This seems indeed to be the correct answer. Never thought of this from the title. Thank you!

Comment: @The Closers: Wait another few minutes, seems that this does not yet work as expected :-)

Comment: What's the matter? Have you tried Owen Waring's answer, too?

Comment: @tombom Yes! If I try Owen Waring's answer in HeidiSQL, it says "0 records affected". I really do not understand this.

Comment: I've tried it again, now it works for several records and then prints **SQL Error (1300): Invalid utf8 character string: 'FC7220'**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own question, the [linked possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951871/how-to-correct-double-encoded-utf-8-strings-sitting-in-mysql-utf8-general-ci-fie) pointed me into some direction but was not the right solution for me.

Instead, I did the following steps (using [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/)):

1. Right-clicked the table in the tree.
2. Selected "Edit"
3. Changed the drop-down value of "Default collation" to "latin_german1_ci". Did *not* tick the "Convert data" checkbox.
4. Clicked the "Save" button at the bottom.
5. Changed the drop-down value of "Default collation" to "utf8_general_ci". Did *not* tick the "Convert data" checkbox.
6. Clicked the "Save" button at the bottom.

After that, I could successfully execute my statements like e.g.

```
UPDATE `mydb`.`mytable` SET `mycolumn` = REPLACE(`mycolumn`, 'Ã¼', 'ü');
```

Answer (score 2):

Your 'Umlauts' are NOT broken! These are just encoded as utf-8 and so your 'u with two dots' results in a utf-8 2-byte sequence. There is nothing wrong about it. Your problem is that your viewer possibly displays in ANSI encoding (iso-8859-1) which results in a 1:1 relation between byte and character. However a viewer must "decode" utf-8 sequences to get the codepoint for the character, otherwise it will simply display the utf-8 start-byte as well as following-byte/s as the character it represents in ANSI. I bet your view is not configured to view utf-8 encoded text. Just configure it as appropriate and you're done.

Let your 'u with two dots' be utf-8 encoded, then every viewer worldwide can decode it's codepoint which is a unique unicode codepoint. Remember that if your 'u with two dots' is ANSI encoded, it will show possibly a different character when displayed with a different ANSI encoding, for example iso-8859-5.

Comment: [I'm the guy linking to Joel's Unicode article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) all the time, so I'm pretty sure that  I know how this encoding stuff works ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the link to Joel's Unicode article, it is really well explained, especially when it comes to the utf-8 encoding part. I'd appreciate if the article would become completed by explaining how codepoints bigger than 0xFFFF (characters beyond the Basic Multilingual Plane BMP) fit into wchar-arrays e. g. how this is done in UTF-16 (the lovely surrogates).

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, MySQL is correct in storing `ü` as `Ã¼` using UTF-8 collation *`utf8_general_ci`* or better *`utf_unicode_ci`*. [(Discussion on why to prefer *`utf8_unicode_ci`*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci#766996)

Now, it matters how you decode your UTF-encoded SQL string before you print it on the frontend like HTML, Android or iOS.

**HTML**

In case of HTML, set utf-8 charset in `<head>` section of HTML page, German character `ü` will show correctly.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    ...
</head>
```

If doesn't, then in case of PHP wrap your variable in `utf_decode()` function before printing it.

*Note: If you are not using PHP with MySQL, lookup for utf-8 decode function in your language of choice.*

**Android**

In case of Android use

```
Html.fromHtml(String).toString();
```

**iOS**

In case of iOS use

```
(NSString *)stringByDecodingHTMLEntities;
```