# Same php scripts, same mysql db, different displays or accented characters

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

I just copied a website to a new server (files + db) then I have the exact same php scripts and the exact same db.
I have that table :

```
CREATE TABLE `cours` (
  `idcours` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `titrecours` varchar(256) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And that record :

```
INSERT INTO `creforma_cours` (`idcours`, `titrecours`) VALUES
(-1040, 'DÃ©monstration');
```

The HEX value for `DÃ©monstration` is `44C383C2A96D6F6E7374726174696F6E` (checked in original and new db)

I display that value with php `print` without any decoding (the php file if in UTF8 no bom).
On the original website, it is displayed `Démonstration` but on the new one it is displayed `DÃ©monstration`.

How can it be different ? Is there a configuration of php or mariadb-server that can prevent decoding ?

Comment: You have *literally* the characters "Ã©" in your database. That's… messed up. Literally. You have messed up your database data. You need to fix that. You don't want garbage stored in your database, you want "é" instead. It happened to decode on your old server through some (un-)fortuitous combination of mistreating that garbage in reverse. On your new server, you apparently have set up all the encoding handling correctly, and are now seeing the actual garbage you have in your database.

Comment: The answer you give doesn't reply to my question, sorry. I have a better anwser.

Comment: See "Mojibake" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 0):

THE BAD WAY :

I found the difference in the mysql conf file, I commented these two lines :

```
# MySQL/MariaDB default is Latin1, but in Debian we rather default to the full
# utf8 4-byte character set. See also client.cnf

#character-set-server  = utf8mb4
#collation-server      = utf8mb4_general_ci
```

OK, it would be better to let those lines uncommented and correct all my tables but it's too much work for now. And that's a solution nobody seems to know !

THE GOOD WAY :

I find the solution to correct the whole database(s) at once [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951871/how-to-correct-double-encoded-utf-8-strings-sitting-in-mysql-utf8-general-ci-fie#answer-9089682) :

```
mysqldump -p --skip-set-charset --default-character-set=latin1 --all-databases > dump.sql
mysql -p --default-character-set=utf8 < dump.sql
```

Comment: Simpler:  `CONVERT(BINARY(CONVERT('DÃ©m' USING latin1)) USING utf8mb4)`